# Unable to make a new page appear on wagtail admin

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to get started with wagtail cms. I have followed the steps from http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.3/getting_started/tutorial.html and tried to create a new page but somehow I don't see the page appearing on the admin dashboard even after creating the model. I am using https://c9.io/ for hosting and rest all things are similar. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the homepage which appears after clicking on Explorer and hoping to find the newly created pages there. But I had to click on add new child page to find all the newly created pages.

Comment: Can you post it here for reference? Just in case others have similar experiences

Comment: Posted the mistake I had made

Answer (score 0):

On https://c9.io/YOUR_ACCOUNT

Create a new workspace and Choose a template --- Blank

```
sudo pip3 install django
sudo pip3 install wagtail
wagtail start mysite
cd mysite
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
python3 manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT
```